# How to use change document for ME_UPDATE_INFORECORD in abap customer report

Tags: abap

In custom report I use the function module `ME_UPDATE_INFORECORD` to change the field "vendor material number" in purchasing info records of some specified suppliers.

It works perfectly, but no change documents are written.

Could you please check in my simple code and give me a hint how to properly call the function module `ME_CREATE_CHANGEDOC_INFOREC` entitled "Generation of change documents for info record".

```
REPORT zic_pir_update.

TABLES : eine,eina.

PARAMETERS : pa_esokz TYPE eine-esokz OBLIGATORY VALUE CHECK DEFAULT '0'.
SELECT-OPTIONS: so_matnr FOR eina-matnr DEFAULT '10016.70.001.03'.

TYPES: BEGIN OF ts_t001w,
     werks       TYPE t001w-werks,
     zz_ic_lifnr TYPE t001w-zz_ic_lifnr,
   END OF ts_t001w.

DATA gt_t001w TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ts_t001w.


CLASS lcl_checkauthority DEFINITION.
 PUBLIC SECTION.

TYPES: ls_001w TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ts_t001w.

CLASS-METHODS :get_t001w
  EXPORTING
    lt_t001w TYPE ls_001w.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_checkauthority IMPLEMENTATION.

METHOD get_t001w.

SELECT werks ,zz_ic_lifnr FROM t001w
   INTO TABLE @lt_t001w
    WHERE zz_ic_lifnr <> ' '. "For intercompany process, plant is assigned 
to intercompany supplier.
SORT lt_t001w BY werks.

LOOP AT lt_t001w ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_t001w>).

  AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'M_MATE_WRK' ID 'WERKS' FIELD <lfs_t001w>-werks
ID 'ACTVT' FIELD '03'.
  IF sy-subrc NE 0.
    MESSAGE e120(m7) WITH <lfs_t001w>-werks.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.

ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_pir DEFINITION.

PUBLIC SECTION.

TYPES: BEGIN OF ts_mbew,
         bklas       TYPE mbew-bklas,
         zz_ic_lifnr TYPE t001w-zz_ic_lifnr,
       END OF ts_mbew.

TYPES : ts_eina_o TYPE eina,
        ts_eine_o TYPE eine,
        ts_eina_i TYPE eina,
        ts_eine_i TYPE eine.


TYPES : ls_cd_eina_ua     TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF veinaua,
        ls_cd_eina_ua_old TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF veinaua.

CLASS-METHODS :get_eina_eine
  EXPORTING
    ls_eina_o          TYPE ts_eina_o
    ls_eine_o          TYPE ts_eine_o
    ls_mbew            TYPE ts_mbew
    ls_eina_i          TYPE ts_eina_i
    ls_eine_i          TYPE ts_eine_i
    lt_cd_eina_ua      TYPE ls_cd_eina_ua
    lt_cd_eina_ua_old  TYPE ls_cd_eina_ua_old
    lst_cd_eina_ua     TYPE veinaua
    lst_cd_eina_ua_old TYPE veinaua.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_pir IMPLEMENTATION.

METHOD get_eina_eine.

SELECT * FROM eina INTO ls_eina_o
FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_t001w
WHERE lifnr = gt_t001w-zz_ic_lifnr AND
       loekz EQ ' ' AND
        matnr IN so_matnr.

  IF ls_eina_o-idnlf EQ ls_eina_o-matnr.
    WRITE: / 'PIR'(001),ls_eina_o-infnr, 'Vendor'(002), ls_eina_o-lifnr, 
'Material'(003) , ls_eina_o-matnr, 'not neccessary update'(004).
  ELSE.

    CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_MATN1_OUTPUT'
      EXPORTING
        input  = ls_eina_o-matnr
      IMPORTING
        output = ls_eina_o-matnr
      EXCEPTIONS
        OTHERS = 2.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
                 WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
    ENDIF.

    IF ls_eina_o-idnlf EQ ls_eina_o-matnr.
      WRITE: / 'PIR'(001),ls_eina_o-infnr, 'Vendor'(002), ls_eina_o-lifnr, 
'Material'(003) , ls_eina_o-matnr, 'not neccessary update'(004).
    ELSE.

      IF ( sy-subrc <> 0 AND sy-batch = 'X' ).
        WRITE :/ 'no PIR found'(005).
        RETURN.
      ENDIF.

      SELECT * FROM eine INTO ls_eine_o
      FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_t001w

      WHERE infnr = ls_eina_o-infnr AND
             werks = gt_t001w-werks AND
              esokz = pa_esokz AND
               loekz EQ ' '.

        ls_eina_i = ls_eina_o.
        ls_eine_i = ls_eine_o.
        ls_eina_o-idnlf = ls_eina_o-matnr.

        CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_MATN1_INPUT'
          EXPORTING
            input        = ls_eina_o-matnr
          IMPORTING
            output       = ls_eina_o-matnr
          EXCEPTIONS
            length_error = 1
            OTHERS       = 2.
        IF sy-subrc <> 0.
          MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
                     WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
        ENDIF.

 *check if it is IC Material. "#EC CI_BUFFJOIN
        SELECT  mbew~bklas, t001w~zz_ic_lifnr
        UP TO 1 ROWS BYPASSING BUFFER

         FROM mbew AS mbew INNER JOIN t001w AS t001w ON "#EC CI_BUFFJOIN

          mbew~bwkey = t001w~bwkey

        INTO @ls_mbew

        WHERE  mbew~matnr = @ls_eina_o-matnr AND
                  zz_ic_lifnr = @ls_eina_o-lifnr.
        ENDSELECT.

*check if supplier is IC.
        IF ( ls_eina_o-lifnr EQ ls_mbew-zz_ic_lifnr ).

          CALL FUNCTION 'ME_UPDATE_INFORECORD'
            EXPORTING
              xeina    = ls_eina_o  "new
              xeine    = ls_eine_o  "new
              yeina    = ls_eina_i  "old
              yeine    = ls_eine_i  "old
              reg_eina = ls_eina_o. "new


          lst_cd_eina_ua-idnlf = ls_eina_o-idnlf .
          lst_cd_eina_ua_old-idnlf = ls_eina_i-idnlf .

          lst_cd_eina_ua-infnr = ls_eina_o-infnr .
          lst_cd_eina_ua_old-infnr = ls_eina_i-infnr .

          APPEND :
          lst_cd_eina_ua TO lt_cd_eina_ua,
          lst_cd_eina_ua_old TO lt_cd_eina_ua_old.

          WRITE : / 'PIR updated'(006),ls_eina_o-infnr, 'Vendor'(002), 
 ls_eina_o-lifnr, 'Material'(003) , ls_eina_o-matnr.

        ELSE.
          WRITE: / 'Material' , ls_eina_o-matnr, 'Vendor'(002), ls_eina_o- 
lifnr, 'is not equeal to'(007), 'Vendor'(002),ls_mbew-zz_ic_lifnr.

        ENDIF.
      ENDSELECT.

    ENDIF .
  ENDIF.
ENDSELECT.

CALL FUNCTION 'ME_CREATE_CHANGEDOC_INFOREC'
  TABLES
    cd_eina_ua     = lt_cd_eina_ua
    cd_eina_ua_old = lt_cd_eina_ua_old
  .  "  ME_CREATE_CHANGEDOC_INFOREC

COMMIT WORK.

IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
  "All OK
ENDIF.

 ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
*method call for authority check.
CALL METHOD lcl_checkauthority=>get_t001w
IMPORTING
  lt_t001w = gt_t001w.

*method call for find for intercompany purchase info records
CALL METHOD lcl_pir=>get_eina_eine.


END-OF-SELECTION.
```

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: Did you try `ME_CREATE_CHANGEDOC_INFOREC` as it was proposed to you [here](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3954111)?

Comment: Hello , i changed FM from 'ME_UPDATE_INFORECORD' to 'ME_DIRECT_INPUT_INFORECORD' and next FM  from 'ME_UPDATE_INFORECORD' to 'ME_POST_INFORECORD' and it works. Please closed this request. Regards Wojtek

Comment: So post this solution as answer for others so they can use it.

Answer (score 1):

solution i changed FM from 'ME_UPDATE_INFORECORD' to 'ME_DIRECT_INPUT_INFORECORD' and next FM from 'ME_UPDATE_INFORECORD' to 'ME_POST_INFORECORD' and it works. Please closed this request. Below final code.

```
REPORT zic_pir_update LINE-SIZE 150.

TABLES : eina.

PARAMETERS : pa_esokz TYPE eine-esokz OBLIGATORY VALUE CHECK DEFAULT '0'.
SELECT-OPTIONS: so_matnr FOR eina-matnr.

TYPES: BEGIN OF ts_t001w,
     werks       TYPE t001w-werks,
     zz_ic_lifnr TYPE t001w-zz_ic_lifnr,
   END OF ts_t001w.

DATA gt_t001w TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ts_t001w.

*example with local class/exporting**************************
CLASS lcl_checkauthority DEFINITION.
PUBLIC SECTION.

TYPES: BEGIN OF ts_t001w,
         werks       TYPE t001w-werks,
         zz_ic_lifnr TYPE t001w-zz_ic_lifnr,
       END OF ts_t001w.

TYPES: ls_t001w TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ts_t001w.

CLASS-METHODS :get_t001w
  EXPORTING
    lt_t001w TYPE ls_t001w.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_checkauthority IMPLEMENTATION.

METHOD get_t001w.

SELECT werks ,zz_ic_lifnr FROM t001w
   INTO TABLE @lt_t001w
    WHERE zz_ic_lifnr <> ' '. "For intercompany process, plant is assigned to 
intercompany supplier.
SORT lt_t001w BY werks.

LOOP AT lt_t001w ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_t001w>).

  AUTHORITY-CHECK OBJECT 'M_MATE_WRK' ID 'WERKS' FIELD <lfs_t001w>-werks
ID 'ACTVT' FIELD '03'.
  IF sy-subrc NE 0.
    MESSAGE e120(m7) WITH <lfs_t001w>-werks.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.

ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_pir DEFINITION.

PUBLIC SECTION.

TYPES : ts_eina_o TYPE eina,
        ts_eine_o TYPE eine,
        ts_eina_i TYPE eina,
        ts_eine_i TYPE eine,
        ts_eina   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF eina.

 *reconstruct the table type without the corresponding input fields using the type 
  addition RANGE OF.
TYPES sv_matnr TYPE RANGE OF eina-matnr.

CLASS-METHODS :get_eina_eine
  IMPORTING
    pv_esokz  TYPE eine-esokz
    sv_matnr  TYPE sv_matnr
  EXPORTING
    ls_eina_o TYPE ts_eina_o
    ls_eine_o TYPE ts_eine_o
    ls_eina_i TYPE ts_eina_i
    ls_eine_i TYPE ts_eine_i
    lt_eina_o TYPE ts_eina
    lt_eina_n TYPE ts_eina
    ls_eina_n TYPE ts_eina_o.

 ENDCLASS.

 CLASS lcl_pir IMPLEMENTATION.

METHOD get_eina_eine.

SELECT * FROM eina INTO TABLE lt_eina_o FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_t001w
   WHERE lifnr = gt_t001w-zz_ic_lifnr AND
         loekz EQ ' ' AND
          matnr IN sv_matnr.

* batch job found no entry.
 IF ( sy-subrc <> 0 AND sy-batch = 'X' ).
  WRITE :/ 'no PIR found'(005).
  RETURN.
 ENDIF.

 LOOP AT lt_eina_o INTO ls_eina_o.

 *If in PIR 'vendor material number' eina-idnlf does not equal with the material in 
 the form 0000000XXXXXXXXXXXX.
  IF ls_eina_o-idnlf EQ ls_eina_o-matnr.
    WRITE: / 'PIR'(001),ls_eina_o-infnr, 'Vendor'(002), ls_eina_o-lifnr, 
  'Material'(003) , ls_eina_o-matnr, 'not neccessary update in field Vendor Mat. 
  No.'(004).
  ELSE.

       * CONVERSION from 0000000XXXXXXXXXXXX to XXXXX.XX.XXX.XX
     CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_MATN1_OUTPUT'
      EXPORTING
        input  = ls_eina_o-matnr
      IMPORTING
        output = ls_eina_o-matnr
      EXCEPTIONS
        OTHERS = 2.
    IF sy-subrc <> 0.
      MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
                 WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
    ENDIF.

  *If in PIR 'vendor material number' eina-idnlf does not equal with the material in 
  the form of XXXXX.XX.XXX.XX
    IF ls_eina_o-idnlf EQ ls_eina_o-matnr.
      WRITE: / 'PIR'(001),ls_eina_o-infnr, 'Vendor'(002), ls_eina_o-lifnr,  
 'Material'(003) , ls_eina_o-matnr, 'not neccessary update in field Vendor Mat.  
  no.'(004).
    ELSE.

      SELECT * FROM eine INTO ls_eine_o
        UP TO 1 ROWS
         FOR ALL ENTRIES IN gt_t001w
          WHERE infnr = ls_eina_o-infnr AND
                 werks = gt_t001w-werks AND
                  esokz = pv_esokz AND
                   loekz EQ ' '.
      ENDSELECT.

      IF sy-subrc = 0.

   *CONVERSION from XXXXX.XX.XXX.XX to 0000000XXXXXXXXXXXX.
        CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_MATN1_INPUT'
          EXPORTING
            input        = ls_eina_o-matnr
          IMPORTING
            output       = ls_eina_o-matnr
          EXCEPTIONS
            length_error = 1
            OTHERS       = 2.
        IF sy-subrc <> 0.
          MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
                     WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
        ENDIF.

        ls_eina_i = ls_eina_o.
        ls_eine_i = ls_eine_o.
        ls_eina_o-idnlf = ls_eina_o-matnr.

   *FM to change condition records into inforecord
        CALL FUNCTION 'ME_INITIALIZE_INFORECORD'.
        CALL FUNCTION 'ME_DIRECT_INPUT_INFORECORD'
          EXPORTING
            activity         = 'V'              " Aktivitätstyp: 'A' Anzeigen, 'V' 
   Pflegen
            i_eina           = ls_eina_o        " Infosatz allgemeine Daten neuer 
   Stand
             o_eina           = ls_eina_i        " Infosatz allgemeine Daten alter 
   Stand
            i_no_suppose     = 'X'              " Keine Vorschlagsdaten setzen
            i_vorga          = 'A'              " Wer ruft den Funktionsbaustein auf?
     *               i_skip_nr_check  =                  " Skip number range check
          IMPORTING
            e_eina           = ls_eina_n        " Infosatz allgemeine Daten neuer  
    stand
          EXCEPTIONS
            textname_invalid = 1
            OTHERS           = 2.
        IF sy-subrc <> 0.
          MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
            WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.

        ELSE.
          APPEND:ls_eina_n TO lt_eina_n.

          CALL FUNCTION 'ME_POST_INFORECORD'
            TABLES
              t_eina_i = lt_eina_n " Einkaufsinfosatz - allgemeine Daten: Neue Sätze
            EXCEPTIONS
              OTHERS   = 2.

          IF sy-subrc = 0.

            CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
              EXPORTING
                wait = abap_true.

            WRITE : / 'Vendor Mat. No. in PIR updated'(006) COLOR COL_KEY,ls_eina_o- 
          infnr COLOR COL_KEY, 'Vendor'(002) COLOR COL_KEY,
             ls_eina_o-lifnr COLOR COL_KEY, 'Material'(003) COLOR COL_KEY , 
          ls_eina_o-matnr COLOR COL_KEY.

          ENDIF.
        ENDIF.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
  ENDIF.
 ENDLOOP.

 ENDMETHOD.

 ENDCLASS.

 START-OF-SELECTION.

*method call for authority check.
 CALL METHOD lcl_checkauthority=>get_t001w
 IMPORTING
  lt_t001w = gt_t001w.

 *method call for find for intercompany purchase info records
  CALL METHOD lcl_pir=>get_eina_eine
  EXPORTING
  pv_esokz = pa_esokz
  sv_matnr = so_matnr[].

  END-OF-SELECTION.
```